# How to setup a platform to develop iOS Apps with Windows and Java knowledge

Tags: android, ios, development-environment

I am not sure if I am right here to ask this, I just try it. I also know that this question is similar to 22358, but I don't know if this is actual and my situation is probably different.

I am looking for a Development setup to port an Android app to IOS.

- My Development Environment is a VMWare running Windows7 with Eclipse and Android SDK.
- I now like to port my app to an IOS app (Iphone, Ipad).
- My App uses an SQLite Database, which I like to resuse.
- My Efforts in the App was : 40% App Development, 60% Database-Content with own Javatools.( Means that the most effort wasn't the app itself with Android-SDK, but maintaining the content with selfdeveloped java tools)
- I do not want to buy any new Hardware. My Desk is full :-)

I am looking now for a good development setup for howto to port the app efficiently and also longterm stable. (Sorry for the bad english)

My thoughts so far:
The best for me would be to have the XCode Development Tools on the same VMWare as I have already my Eclipse to Develop Android and tools. But so far my research concludes, that there is no official development tool on windows. All other adaptions are not looking like longterm solution to me ?

I could install a VMWare with a XOS built. But all sources for the builds feeled not reliable to me (torrents etc...), so I am not sure if this is allowed ?

Any good idea howto do this today (2015) ?

Additional Info about my current System:

-VMWare Host:Windows8.1 64Bit

-VMWare Guest:Windows7 Home Premium

-VMWare Workstation: 9.0.4 build-1945795

-Hardware: 16GB Ram, Intel(R) i7-4790K 4Ghz, Lots of Disk.

Comment: Your guest OS is Windows 7. What is your host OS, then ?

Comment: My Host is Windows8. My Guest is Windows7. So my entire development environment runns on windows7 with eclipse and Android SDK and a lot of tools to maintain the SQLite Database.

Comment: Well, you can have Mac OS X running on your Windows 8. I know a way out.

Comment: @Lance Preston : If you would suggest this way for a logterm project I would be very interrested in howto do this.

Comment: Tell me more about your computer's configuration. Also tell me about the version of `VMware` you are running so that I can guide you better.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I added additional Info on my current System in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `VMware` is made to run `Mac OS X` nor `Mac OS X` is manufactured to run on virtual environments like `VMware` or `Virtual Box`. But, unlocking `VMware` can boost its capabilities to run a `Modified Mac OS X` which is hardly any different from an untouched one from Apple Inc.

---

**Step 1 :** You need to download something called a `VMware Unlocker`. A simple `google` search with the query `VMware Unlocker for VMware 9` will help you get through.


**Step 2 :** Download a `Pre-configured VMware Image` of `Mac OS X Mavericks`. A `google` search will help out again.

**Step 3 :** Get the `VMsvga2` driver for better graphics support on a virtual `Mac OS X`

---

I have just outlined the steps. You can visualize everything in a video here on `youtube` about 
[How To Install OS X Mavericks 10.9 Retail On Windows PC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubISvBqVQqA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this good overview. I'll give it a try. Are there any appdevelopers out there, which would also suggest this approach ?

Comment: @user1344545 : I have a flair for iOS development and I am writing a few apps. I have a Windows Laptop and I am running Mac OS X virtually. I did it in the way I just suggested you. It is tried and tested and believe me, it works. Give it a shot. You won't regret.

Comment: Thanks a lot and this gives me hope. I went through the tutorial and managed to start the VW with OS X Maverick. At the step to signin I wanted to create a new Apple ID and it says that "This Mac is no longer eligible to create Apple ID accounts. Create an Apple ID using a different device." . I guess I need an account to download the developertools from appstore ? Any hints ?

Comment: Completely remove the Mac OS X VM. Re-do the installation and during the first-time setup, just skip the registration, signing in and all that.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I did it and worked fine. I could work with the OS with no problem. Then I tried to download and install the Xcode Development Environment. The OS wants me to update to Yosemite, otherwise I can't install Xcode. I updated to Yosemite, but now I have Problems with the Screen. I will open a new question for this and will accept this answer, because it showed me the right way to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1344545 : Thanks for accepting the answer. Kindly give an up-vote to the answer.

Comment: @user1344545 : I can help you out with the Xcode related problem you are facing

Comment: Thank you very much for your supply. In fact I do have other questions regarding OSX development. I am still not sure if I should buy a MINI-MAC or stay in a VM. Would it be possible to contact you directly ? Would also compensate your effort.

Comment: Yes. Sure. You can contact me directly. Do let me know how to get in touch with you beyond StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

You need a Mac and Xcode - sorry :)

Comment: After the answers my yosmite is running in my vmware and I am using Xcode in it. So it can work.

Answer (score 0):

The following article is very dated but since you said you wanted a reputable source this is probably as good as it gets:

http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox

If you follow the links to updated versions of instructions you should end up here:

http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/05/os-x-mavericks-in-virtualbox-with-niresh.html

Comment: Can you accept my answer if it is the accepted answer?